# show all axis lines without zoom linechart

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linechart, ios-charts

Hello i want to see all records in line-chart but without zoom, at this time if i don't zoom it does not show lines  u can see in screenshots please guide me [This image is Without Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0c9y.png), for example if there are 100 records i want to draw all lines but without zoom i need to see them

[After zoom i can see lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvJDY.png)

this is how i set data

```
func setDataCount() {
  //  lineChartView.clear()
    var systolicArray :[ChartDataEntry] = []
    var diastolicArray:[ChartDataEntry] = []
    var pulseArray:[ChartDataEntry] = []
    systolicArray.removeAll()
    diastolicArray.removeAll()
    pulseArray.removeAll()

    let systolicSortingByDate = systolic.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date})
  //  print("---Dumb:\(dump(systolicSortingByDate))")
    for data in systolic {
        let timeIntervalForDate: TimeInterval = AppData.stringToDate(date: data.date).timeIntervalSince1970
        let systolicChart = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(timeIntervalForDate), y: Double(data.systolicReading), icon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "editprofile"))
        systolicArray.append(systolicChart)
    }

    for data in diastolic {
        let timeIntervalForDate: TimeInterval = AppData.stringToDate(date: data.date).timeIntervalSince1970
        let diastolicChart = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(timeIntervalForDate), y: Double(data.diastolicReading), icon:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "editprofile"))
        diastolicArray.append(diastolicChart)
    }

    for data in pulse {
        let timeIntervalForDate: TimeInterval = AppData.stringToDate(date: data.date).timeIntervalSince1970
        let diastolicChart = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(timeIntervalForDate), y: Double(data.pulseReading), icon:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "editprofile"))
        pulseArray.append(diastolicChart)
    }

    print("SystolicCount:\(systolic.count)")
    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(values: systolicArray, label: "Systolic")
    set1.drawIconsEnabled = false
    set1.highlightLineDashLengths = [5, 2.5]
    set1.setColor(UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "ff8a00"))
    set1.setCircleColor((UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "ff8a00")))
    set1.lineWidth = 4
    set1.circleRadius = 3

    set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true
    set1.valueFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 9)
    set1.formLineDashLengths = [5, 2.5]
    set1.formLineWidth = 2
    set1.formSize = 15

    let set2 = LineChartDataSet(values: diastolicArray, label: "Diastolic")
    set2.drawIconsEnabled = false
    set2.setColor(.black)
    set2.setCircleColor(.black)
    set2.lineWidth = 4
    set2.circleRadius = 3
    set2.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true
    set2.valueFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 9)
    set2.formLineDashLengths = [5, 2.5]
    set2.formLineWidth = 2
    set2.formSize = 15

    let set3 = LineChartDataSet(values: pulseArray, label: "Pulse")
    set3.drawIconsEnabled = false
    set3.setColor(UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "e83636"))
    set3.setCircleColor(UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "e83636"))
    set3.lineWidth = 4
    set3.circleRadius = 3
    set3.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true
    set3.valueFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 9)
    set3.formLineDashLengths = [5, 2.5]
    set3.formLineWidth = 2
    set3.formSize = 15

    lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = true
    lineChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(systolicArray.count, force: false)
    let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [set1,set2,set3])
    lineChartView.data = data
    let xAxisValue = lineChartView.xAxis
    xAxisValue.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate
    xAxisValue.setLabelCount(4, force: false)
    lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 3, yAxisDuration: 3)
 //   lineChartView.xAxis.granularity = 0.5

}
```

Comment: May need more info. FWIW, I've seen similar odd behaviour re plots not appearing when the data has not been sorted correctly. Points must be added in order (incrementing across X-axis). I see you have one sorting line commented out, but only for systolic. Firstly, make sure your data is sorted in date order and try it again. Otherwise, try adding fewer datapoints to start with (e.g. two fixed points) with the same graphing configuration and see what happens.

Comment: i need data in sequence?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'll have a look later for the docs on that reqt, but as I say, I've seen odd plots like that you seem to have here when the data is not ordered (chronologically in this case). So check that and let me know. i.e. let sortedSystolic = systolic.sorted(by: {$0.date < $1.date}), for data in sortedSystolic